# calculating size of memory in bits and number of locations

Tags: memory, memory-management, bit

So I was asked this question in exam, and I havent been able to find an answer anywhere yet. So i was wondering how to calculate it..

calculate the size of memory in bits if there are 32 address lines and 2 bytes of addressable memory. Also, calculate the number of locations

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, that should be 2 ^ 32 (4294967296) 16-bit (2 bytes) memory locations = 68719476736 bits of memory.

> If you have a byte-addressable memory (i.e every byte in the memory
> has an address) and an address bus of size 12 (i.e 12 wires in the
> address bus or 12 bits in the Memory Address Register). How much
> maximum RAM can you support?
>
> **Solution:**
>
> If there are just 2 bits in the address, then there can only be 4
> addresses, viz.
>
> 00, 01, 10, 11
>
> If 3 bits are allowed in the address, then we can have maximum 8
> addresses:
>
> 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111
>
> So, if we have n bits to store an Address (n-bits in Address Register)
> or n-wires to transfer the address (Address bus of size 10), then we
> can have RAM of 2^n addresses.
>
> Now there are 2^n addresses, and each address is of 1 byte (because its
> a byte-addressable memory, so every byte will have a unique address or
> every address will be of 1-byte long).
>
> Hence, total memory will be equal to
>
> size of each address * number of addresses = 8 * 2^n
>
> If n=12 (as given in the question)
>
> Size of memory = 8 * 2^12 bits = 2^12 bytes = 2^2 Kilo Bytes (2^10 Bytes =
> 1 KB) = 4 KB

**References:**

- [How much byte-addressable memory you can use with 12 bits address bus](https://www.ritambhara.in/how-much-byte-addressable-memory-you-can-use-with-12-bits-address-bus/)
- [Unit of address resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Unit_of_address_resolution)